# Maximum and minimum temperature from different weather stations for each of 365 days in the span of 2005 to 2015

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

The following is the dataframe  having maximum and minimum temperature from different weather stations for each day from 2005 to 2015.I have to plot a line graph for max and min temperature for each day of 365 days of a year in the  span of 2005-2015.Should ,I group them by date and element?How should i approach this problem?
For example take january 5 , then i have to find the maximum of all january 5 TMAX(Data_Value) from the year 2005 to 2015 similary for TMIN.

```
             ID       Date  Element Data_Value
0   USW00094889 2014-11-12  TMAX    22
1   USC00208972 2009-04-29  TMIN    56
2   USC00200032 2008-05-26  TMAX    278
3   USC00205563 2005-11-11  TMAX    139
4   USC00200230 2014-02-27  TMAX    -106
5   USW00014833 2010-10-01  TMAX    194
6   USC00207308 2010-06-29  TMIN    144
7   USC00203712 2005-10-04  TMAX    289
8   USW00004848 2007-12-14  TMIN    -16
9   USC00200220 2011-04-21  TMAX    72
10  USC00205822 2013-01-16  TMAX    11
```

Comment: each day or linear chart? you don't have min mac for each year: 2007 max is missing, 2008 min, 2009 max, 20011 max etc, is it part of your task/exercise?

Comment: For example take january 5 , then i have to find the maximum of TMAX(Data_Value) for january 5 from the year 2005 to 2015 similary for TMIN.I Have to line plot of TMAX for 365 days .Maximum of each day of a year in the given span of  years,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to recreate your sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":np.repeat(pd.date_range("2005-01-01","2015-12-31"),2)})
df["Element"] = np.resize(["TMAX","TMIN"],len(df))
df["Data_Values"] = np.random.randint(-106,300,len(df))
```

From here you should first `pivot` your `Element` column:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index="Date", columns="Element",values="Data_Values", aggfunc=["min","max"])

print (df)

            min       max     
Element    TMAX TMIN TMAX TMIN
Date                          
2005-01-01  167  215  240  215
2005-01-02  -34  181  100  181
2005-01-03  131  227  221  227
2005-01-04  107  295  167  295
2005-01-05   64  -72  191  -72
...         ...  ...  ...  ...
2015-12-27   11 -101  218 -101
2015-12-28   21  237  269  237
2015-12-29 -106  100  144  100
2015-12-30   40  217  241  217
2015-12-31  -20  -75  109  -75
```

Then you can `groupby` month and date:

```
print (df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).agg({('min', 'TMIN'):"min",('max', 'TMAX'):"max"}))

           min  max
          TMIN TMAX
Date Date          
1    1     -76  287
     2     -78  282
     3    -101  283
     4     -81  290
     5     -72  282
     6     -37  291
     7     -49  299
...
```

Comment: df = df.pivot(index="Date", columns="Element",values="Data_Value")
I tried the above code  after seeing your answer  but  there is a error
`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
`

Comment: You have more than one `TMAX` and `TMIN` for each individual date?

Comment: Yes , for example see below:


`Date ID Element Data_Value `
`2005-01-01 USW00004848 TMIN 0`
`2005-01-01 USC00207320 TMAX 150`
`2005-01-01 USC00207320 TMIN -11`
`2005-01-01 USW00014833 TMIN -44`
`2005-01-01 USW00014833 TMAX 33`

Comment: In that case you can use `pivot_table` instead. See edited above.

Comment: No, the dataset is from diiferrent weather stations for maximum and minimum temprature for a day  over a span of years(2005-2015).And i need to plot a line plot for tmax and tmin taking 365 days of a year as x-axis,Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you(or we) are missing some datas, but it could be part of the exercise:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

temp_list = [
    ['2009-04-29', 'TMIN', 56],
    ['2008-05-26', 'TMAX', 278],
    ['2005-11-11', 'TMAX', 139],
    ['2014-02-27', 'TMAX', -106],
    ['2010-10-01', 'TMAX', 194],
    ['2010-06-29', 'TMIN', 144],
    ['2005-10-04', 'TMAX', 289],
    ['2007-12-14', 'TMIN', -16],
    ['2011-04-21', 'TMAX', 72],
    ['2013-01-16', 'TMAX', 11]
]

column_names = ['date', 'min_max', 'temp']

temperature_df = pd.DataFrame(data=temp_list, columns=column_names)
temperature_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(temperature_df['date'])
temperature_df['date_y'] = temperature_df['date'].dt.year
temperature_df.sort_values(by=['date_y'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)

temperature_df.drop(columns='date', inplace=True)
temperature_df.set_index('date_y', inplace=True)

#pivot
temperature_df = temperature_df.pivot_table(values='temp', index='date_y', columns='min_max')

print(temperature_df)
```

results into:

```
min_max   TMAX   TMIN
date_y               
2005     214.0    NaN
2007       NaN  -16.0
2008     278.0    NaN
2009       NaN   56.0
2010     194.0  144.0
2011      72.0    NaN
2013      11.0    NaN
2014    -106.0    NaN
```

"NaN" are the missing data, then you can interpolate them or just fills them using backford/forward existing data [click](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

I wouldn't fill them up as they are yearly temps, and doesn't mean anything to fill backward/forward, then you can find a way to interpolate (Maybe they expect you to do some research, like global warming on these years/dates...)

if you do need to chart, you could interpolate or scatter.
pandas allow you to interpolate but you will need to install 'scipy'

```
# interpolate
temperature_df['TMAX'] = temperature_df['TMAX'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)
temperature_df['TMIN'] = temperature_df['TMIN'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)

print(temperature_df)
#chart

temperature_df.plot()
plt.show()
```

chart will show:[image]

Then you can ask another question about how to get missing points for the mins or max.
Best!